# sudo is still asking for password despite being in group wheel

Tags: sudo

Help me debug this. I am being prompted for a password when I prefix commands with `sudo` despite the correct settings (I believe).

1. I am in group `wheel`.

   ```bash
   $ groups
   network power users storage lp input audio wheel dilawars
   ```
2. I have uncommented the right line using `visudo`:

   ```
   ##
   ## User privilege specification
   ##
   root ALL=(ALL) ALL

   ## Uncomment to allow members of group wheel to execute any command
   # %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL

   ## Same thing without a password
   %wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
   ```

I've logged out and logged in multiple times, but whenever I say `sudo cmd`, I am prompted for a password.

I am on Majaro Linux.

I noticed the following line in the output from `strace sudo ls`:

```
write(2, "effective uid is not 0, is /usr/"..., 133effective uid is not
 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or
 an NFS file system without root privileges?) = 133
```

Comment: What exact command(s) are you running? If it's something like `ls`, where are you using it?

Comment: The exact command is `sudo p0f -d` but to test the sudo, I also did `sudo ls /var/log` etc.

Comment: It would really help to see the whole `/etc/sudoers`. That seems to be just a snippet.

Comment: `strace sudo ls` is not useful for this case: strace (from normal user) prevents sudo to be suid-root (see `man execve.2`).

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Finally resolved it. I should have posted the full file, the issue was in the last line which reads file from `/etc/sudoer.d` directory. One of the file in this directory was resetting the wheel group rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the user matches more than one rule. In that case the last matching rule wins. So, if you move:

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

to the end of the file, it should work.

Comment: Another thing to consider is if the user is included in anything in `/etc/sudoers.d`.

Comment: Thanks. This was it.  The line at the end of `/etc/sudoers`, `@includedir /etc/sudoer.d` was the culprit. `/etc/sudoer.d` has two files, one of them was using the different rule for the `wheel` group. I made changed in that file and it worked.  Ideally, manjaro should remove the line from `/etc/sudoers` and point to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Aurman executes `sudo -v` to force user's credentials to be cached once at startup. With this option `sudo` by default doesn't ask password only if all matched entries have `NOPASSWD` tag. Thus, if in `/etc/sudoers` you have something like this:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%wheel ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

and you are member of both groups `wheel` and `sudo`, you are asked for password anyway.
You can configure `sudo` to avoid asking for password if at least one matched entry has `NOPASSWD` tag. In `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Defaults verifypw = any
```